# How do I center the form input using MatBlazor?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, matblazor

How do I center the form inputs in this image? I'm using the GridLayout defined here: https://www.matblazor.com/LayoutGrid using form elements defined here https://www.matblazor.com/EditContext
[image]

This is my attempt but i must be missing something:

```
<div class="container login-layout mat">

    <MatCard>
        <MatCardContent>
            <EditForm Model="Login" OnValidSubmit="Success">
                <div class="mat-layout-grid">
                    <div class="mat-layout-grid-inner">

                        <div class="mat-layout-grid-cell mat-layout-grid-cell-span-12">

                            <MatH2>Login</MatH2>
                        </div>

                        <div class="mx-auto
                         mat-layout-grid-cell
                         mat-layout-grid-cell-span-12">


                            <MatTextField ValidationDisabled="true" Label="Username" @bind-Value="Login.Username" />
                            <MatTextField ValidationDisabled="true" Type="Password" Label="Password" @bind-Value="Login.Username" />

                        </div>

                        <div class="mat-layout-grid-cell mat-layout-grid-cell-span-12">

                            <MatButton class="float-right">Log in</MatButton>
                            @*<MatButton class="float-right" @onclick="OnLoginClick">Log in</MatButton>*@
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </EditForm>

            <div class="container">
                <MatCaption>Need an account? </MatCaption>

                <MatButton class="float-right aslkjd-c0ass" @onclick="OnSignUp">Sign up</MatButton>

            </div>
        </MatCardContent>
    </MatCard>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

mx-auto or say margin auto in x axis work in div if you provide it a width or max-width. try using it on input field itself or try giving div a width or you can use  flex justify content: center and flex-direction: column on the div

Comment: Is there a way to set the width using MatBlazor?